# Limit my openshift project to a maximum of 2 full CPU, 2G of memory using a quota

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I have a doubt about something I read an openshift guide related to resource-quotas.

I want to set a resource-quota for my project **to limit it to a maximum** , of let's say 2 full CPU, 2G of memory.
In this case I have to specify in the yaml file of my resource-quota:
*limits.cpu: "2"* and  *limits.memory: "2Gi"*
or :
*requests.cpu: "2"* and  *requests.memory: "2Gi"* ?

In this guide the solution was to simply to execute:  *oc create quota review-quota --hard cpu="2",memory="2G"*

But doing so, I think it sets only the requests.cpu and requests.memory.
If I want *to limit it to a maximum* my project shouldn't I use the *limits* and not the *requets*?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This document should have everything you need: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.6/applications/quotas/quotas-setting-per-project.html

Specifically, you should be creating `limits.cpu` and `limits.memory` rules, as these will enforce

> The sum of CPU limits across all pods in a non-terminal state cannot exceed this value.

and

> The sum of memory limits across all pods in a non-terminal state cannot exceed this value.